Sveltekit static app in webview2 .NET form "tauri like app but in .NET"
I have a project that uses .NET 8 Windows forms with webview2 and a sveltekit app with a static adapter
this is the link to the repo
In the dev mode when I start the dev server in http:/localhost:3005 with the .net form in debug mode, everything works fine, link to image of the app in dev server
but when I tried in the release mode after I built everything, I had a lot of issues like:

I tried to make winform like this, but i got these cors error and URL to the scripts are not correct here

then I tried to disable cors "web security" to fix that but I got this error

then to solve the issue I used virtual hostname to folder mapping method like this, but I got this error, then when I add /index.html to the virtual hostname i got this error


from here I dont know to what to do to solve this issue and I dont want to use localhost just like tauri, any suggestions

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

First, you had a CORS errors, but once you resolved the CORS problems, it says that the file located at /C:/Users/IslamZaoui/Desktop/projects/sveltekit-webview2-csharp/csharp-src/publish/win-x64/wwwroot/index.html does not exist. Hence, you will need to make sure that the path exists and the OS user who runs the browser has the necessary privileges to it. And of course that the html file there is the one that you expect.

I'm sure that the index.html path is correct, I tried to make an HTTP server to host it in localhost, and worked perfectly but for my project, I don't want to use any server just the static files

@IslamZaoui is the OS user that's running your browser having the necessary privileges to that path?

yes, I made an HTML file that has just hello world in it and it's worked without issues, this is a sveltekit problem and I don't know how to solve it
